# Rules custom action - how can I get the name of just created account

Tags: rules

I am writing custom Rules action which is supposed to create new instance of a field in database. Action triggered on "new account saved"

I need the field to be labelled as the name of just created account.

Tried to use $account->name but the $account variable seems to be empty...

How can I get that name into the action???

Thanks :)